# How can I read non-ascii characters from a file in C?

Tags: c, file-io, non-ascii-characters, huffman-code

I am right now reading in like this:

```
    while (fscanf(in, "%c", infile) != EOF) 
    {
    ch = *infile;
    count++;
    ascii[ch]++;
    }
```

And making my frequency table like this:

```
    void frequency ()
    {
    unsigned long long i;
    for (i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
     if (ascii[i] != 0)
     {
      uniqueLetters++;
      if (i < 33)
     {
    printf("=%llu\t%lu\n", i, ascii[i]);
      }
     else if (i > 126)
  {
    printf("=%llu\t%lu\n", i, ascii[i]);
  }
  else printf("%c\t%lu\n", (int)(i), ascii[i]);
}
   } 
  printf("unique letters: %lu\n", uniqueLetters);
  }
```

(This is for a huffman encoding project and when I try to read in an entire file I completely miss anything above 126...)

Comment: **Do not `scanf()`.** It's horrible. Its usage is unintuitive, it has all sorts of subtle sources of error built in its behavior. Use `fgetc()` instead.

Comment: Well, are you involving any types that don't go above 127? `char`, for instance, which might be `signed char` in your system?

Comment: I am using unsigned char because I have anything from 0-255

Comment: Unrelated note: The organization of your code could use some work. Pick an indentation style and stick with it rigidly, as though lives are at stake. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: I know how to organize it the format just gets wonky when I copy and past it onto this site

Answer (score 1):

Try `fgetc`:

```
FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");

int ch; // return type of fgetc is int
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    ascii[ch]++;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that didn't work either

Comment: @user3366369 do you have any more details on why it didn't work? What were you expecting? What did you see?

Comment: When I read in from a file I get all characters except for characters above 126...it ends with getting a 'z' when there are 3 other characters after...for some reason it doesn't recognize things greater than 126